# Facebook API - FQL url_like table behaving strangely for some users, not returning all URLs liked

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like, facebook-fql, facebook-apps

I am writing a facebook API based app and I ran into a few complications with the URL_like table in FQL with certain facebook accounts

If I run the following query, I expect to get back a list of URLS including web pages on which I have clicked the "like" button:

https://graph.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT+url+FROM+url_like+WHERE+user_id=me()&access_token=TOKEN

However, on my own personal facebook account (the same one I registered the app with), when I run the query, the URLs that show up are only URLs i liked "inside" facebook - URLs that were posted on my wall, or other peoples walls, but not urls that I visited and clicked the "like" button on.

At first I thought this was an issue with account or privacy settings. I adjusted the settings on my facebook account to match the exact settings that my friend had on his facebook account which showed the correct results of the FQL query, but it still gave me the result above.

I deleted the app from the list of approved apps, approved it again, thinking this would change the result with a different access token, but it has not.

Also - this functionality worked correctly on my facebook account before, which makes the predicament even stranger

So here is the question - does anyone know why only certain URLs show up in the URL_like table? was there a change in the facebook API to justify this? Can this error be repeated? Or is my profile just some sort of super glitch?

Thanks in advance, I am at my wits end with this

Comment: What permissions does your access token have? have you got the `user_likes` and `friends_likes` permissions?

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply - my app has user_likes and user_activity permissions. I don't use "friend_like" because I don't have a need for that.